# intern Functional Testing with Frames

Tags: intern

I'm using the intern and writing some functional tests.
The application I am testing uses a lot of Dojo tabs and iframes and I'm having some trouble navigating around with my functional tests.

I can select the iframes using the "frame()" call and this is fine for accessing the nested iframes. However how do I navigate back up? Selenium WebDriver has a defaultContent to return you to the top most frame but I can't find an implementation of this in the Intern WD.

The problem I am having is that I navigate down into a nested iframe and click a button which switches to a different Dojo tab in a higher frame. I can see the browser loading and switching to the new tab but intern is still stuck on the same nested iframe and I can't navigate back up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `null` as the frame identifier switches back to the page’s default content.