# How to proceed AFTER switching frames in InternJS

Tags: javascript, iframe, functional-testing, intern, leadfoot

Can someone tell me how to proceed with referencing an element within an iframe after the switching of frames is done? I've already looked at the solution presented in [How to switch iframes InternJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167427/how-to-switch-iframes-internjs) to no avail, and the information in [intern Functional Testing with Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298840/intern-functional-testing-with-frames) is just not applicable (yet.) The following script returns an error of `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined    type: TypeError`:

```
return Remote
    .findAllByTagName('iframe')
    .then(function (frames) {
        return new Remote.constructor(Remote.session)
            .switchToFrame(frames[0])
            .getProperty('title')
            .then(function (result) {
                expect(result).to.equal('Rich text editor, rtDescAttach');
            });
    });
```

The only reason I can see that the script is failing is that the frame was not located correctly. There are two on the page and I need the first one. Once this is done I'd really like to put the reference to the frame in a page object (which is where I feel it belongs) but I have to be able to successfully locate it first, so no putting the cart before the horse. Suggestions and help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is actually pretty close. The main issue is that `getProperty('title')` won't work in the way it's being used. `getProperty` is an element method, and at the point you're calling it you don't have a valid element on the context stack. Assuming you're trying to get the title of the iframe page, you'll need to use an `execute` callback, like:

```
.switchToFrame(frames[0])
.execute(function () {
    return document.title;
})
.then(function (title) {
    // assert
})
```

Leadfoot has a `getPageTitle` callback, but it always returns the title of the top-level document (the one who's title is in the browser titlebar or tab).

Another minor issue is that the more canonical way to access the remote in a callback is via the `parent` property, like:

```
.then(function (frames) {
    return this.parent
        .switchToFrame(frames[0])
        // ...
})
```

If you want to access elements within an iframe, you'll need to switch frames, reset the search context, and then find the elements, like:

```
.findAllByTagName('iframe')
.then(function (frames) {
    return this.parent
        // clear the search context in this callback
        .end(Infinity)
        // switch to the first frame
        .switchToFrame(frames[0])
        // find an element in the frame, examine its text content
        .findById('foo')
        .getVisibleText()
        .then(function (text) {
            assert.equal(text, 'expected content');
        })
        // switch back to the parent frame when finished
        .switchToParentFrame()
})
// continue testing in parent frame
```

A couple things to note:

1. The search context is local to the command chain, so changes on the `this.parent`-based command chain don't persist on the parent command chain. Basically, there's no need to call `.end()` at the end of the command chain in the callback.
2. The active frame is *not* local to the command chain, so if you change the frame on a `this.parent`-based chain, you'll need to reset it if you want to return to the parent frame after the callback.

Comment: OMG, you just TOTALLY made my day! I will award you the bounty first thing tomorrow morning when it lets me. You have my undying thanks!